# Optimising code to find the unit digit of factorial of given number N

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, factorial

I tried a question from a contest whose exact statement is like this:

```
Given a number N. The task is to find the unit digit of factorial of given 
number N.

Input:
First line of input contains number of testcases T. For each testcase, there 
will be a single line containing N.

Output:
For each testcase, print the unit digit of factorial of N.

Constraints:
1 <= T <= 1000
1 <= N <= 1018
```

and came up with following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
     BufferedReader reader =  
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    int cases = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int i=0;
    while(i<cases){
        fact(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));i++;
    }
}

static void fact(int num){
    int j,fact=1;     
    for(j=1;j<=num;j++){    
        fact=fact*j;    
        }  
        System.out.println(fact%10);
   }
}
```

It gives right output when executed with custom inputs but when all test cases are tried it gives:*"TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED. Optimise your code"*. I tried to use bufferedReader instead of Scanner class but to no effect. I could not find out how could I optimise this code further. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you find the solution

Answer (score 7):

The difference between `BufferedReader` and `Scanner` probably won't be noticeable here. If you benchmark your code you'll probably find that the heaviest part of it the factorial calculation. Offhand, I can't think of a faster way to calculate it, but the trick here that you probably don't have to.

Let's examine the first few factorials:

- 0! = 1 -> Unit digit is 1
- 1! = 1 -> Unit digit is 1
- 2! = 2 -> Unit digit is 2
- 3! = 6 -> Unit digit is 6
- 4! = 24 -> Unit digit is 4
- 5! = 120 -> Unit digit is 0

Any factorial of 6 or larger would be some natural integers multiplied by 5!, which is 120. So, no matter what they are, the unit digit will be 0. With such a small data set, you can just create a cache of all the options instead of calculating the factorial each time over. E.g.:

```
// The index is the factorial to be calculated, the value is the unit digit:
private static final int[] UNITS = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 6, 4};

private static void fact(int f) {
    int unit = 0;
    if (f <= 4) {
        unit = UNITS[f];
    }
    System.out.println(unit);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to compute factorials for this problem. The units digit of `fact(n)` is going to be `0` for `n > 4`. (I'd make a small table for the other possible inputs.)

Comment: Haha how to ruin an algo contest

Comment: Exactly, I had to read the question twice, I couldn't believe this is all they asked for.

Comment: A fun fact: OP claims their program gives the correct answer on all inputs, but the accumulated factorial clearly overflows very soon. How can that give correct answer? The answer is that the trailing bits of the factorial soon become 0 for much the same reason that the decimal representation ends with a lot of 0s. There are just a few values of N which fall between the integer overflow and the accumulation of trailing zeros, and apparently none were tested.